# ActiveReports HTTP handler shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, activereports

Am facing a damn problem for days now. Mine is an active report project and our server is a shared hosting. So obviously I cant install active reports on the server. So I uploaded all the DLL files, Licence files to the server and specified the handlers according to the documentation. After that change my whole application stoped working. its very crucial. Thanks for any kind of support..

THis is my web.config file portion with assesmbly and http handler.

```
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="ActiveReports RPX Handler" path="*.rpx" verb="GET" type="DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.RpxHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
  <add name="ActiveReports WebCache Handler" path="*.ArCacheItem" verb="GET" type="DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.WebCacheAccessHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
  <add name="ActiveReports Compiled Report Handler" path="*.ActiveReport" verb="GET" type="DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.CompiledReportHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
</handlers>
```

Under System.web

```
 <httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.rpx" verb="*" type="DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.RpxHandler, ActiveReports.Web, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
  <add path="*.ActiveReport" verb="*" type="DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.CompiledReportHandler, ActiveReports.Web, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF" />
  <add path="*.ArCacheItem" verb="*" type="DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Web.Handlers.WebCacheAccessHandler, ActiveReports.Web, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc4967777c49a3ff" />
</httpHandlers>
```

And the assesmblies

```
 <add assembly="ActiveReports.Chart, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.Design6, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.Document, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.XlsExport, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports6, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.HtmlExport, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.PdfExport, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.CodeDomSerializer6, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.RtfExport, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.TiffExport, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.TextExport, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.Viewer6, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.Web, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
    <add assembly="ActiveReports.Web.Design, Version=6.2.3681.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CC4967777C49A3FF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are facing issues related to permissions, then I would suggest you to run the application on MediumTrust. Please refer to the following documentation link that will guide you through:
http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arMediumTrustSupport.html

On further searching, I found the following link wherein a similar issue has been discussed on the godaddy’s support page. This might be informative for you:
http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/request-to-add-arcacheitem-handler-to-iis/

Comment: Unfortunately in Godaddy shared hosting that trust level they wont change and without their support we cant change the trust level to medium.